# Monaca Localkitでの開発時にファイルを削除できない

Tags: monaca

Monaca Localkitで開発をしていますが、ファイルを削除してもビルド設定や、リモートビルドを行うと、削除したファイルが復活してしまう現象が起きます。
具体的には、wwwフォルダーやimagesフォルダーからhtmlやpng,jpegなどのファイルを削除してもビルド設定や、リモートビルドを終え、砂時計マークの表示が終わった後、再びフォルダー内を見るとファイルが復活しているというものです。
プログラミングの問題ではなくて、Monaca　IDEの問題だと思うのですが、開発に関わる技術的な質問はこのサイトで行うことになっているため、ここに質問させていただきます。

どなたか、お教えください。

Answer (score 1):

不具合であれば以下より報告してみるのが良いかもしれません。

https://ja.monaca.io/service/index.html

まあこの件に関しては、同様に悩まされていて何度か報告をし、最新バージョン（1.2.8）のLocalkitでは修正されています（少なくとも手元の環境では解消されました）。もし最新版でないなら更新してみては。

Comment: 早速、バージョンアップしてみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決しました。nandai　様、ありがとうございました。